Is life natural?
All life comes from previous life.
Abiogenesis proposes life came from non life.
What is the evidence that supports the truth to either of these propositions?

Miller-Urey experiments and recent studies in micelle formation

@Annika Conclusively which?

The above is evidence for abiogenesis. Also, basic logic suggests that since the big bang was lifeless, and now we have life, that at some point non-life got life started. Even in the bible, we have abiogenesis in Genesis (when God made Adam)

Seems like a better question for biologists. Although phrasing it in this way does seems to lean heavily on the scale, since it doesn't consider that abiogenesis fits into a broader model (or set of models) for the history of life and Earth and the universe (within which all the evidence we have of life and procreation, fits into and supports). Meanwhile, "all life comes from previous life" is just a statement, not a model. It provides no explanation for how that happens or how that would make sense with the evidence we have. At best, it's a deductive statement that's a generalisation fallacy.

@NotThatGuy A statement or proposition is either true or false. You only deduce further truth from valid statements and their conclusions.

@Annika So the genesis of earth and Adam did not come from God, i.e., life? Or do you have a different definition of God? Does all life that we have evidence of come from previous life?

What I'm saying is that even in Genesis, we have god creating adam from dust and "gods breath". We cannot count God as a "lifeform" here otherwise we'd immediately invalidate "all life come from life" - god may be the "source of all life" - but he is not himself an "instance of life". So the argumetn holds -- adam (a lifeform) came from dust and some "god magic" -- both are not life themselves

Biology/chemistry question

@armand -- I thought so too, but I doubt biologists really have much to say on this as abiogenesis is the only coherent answer. No biologist would say life was always present in the universe, and as I show in my answer and comments, it doesn't jive with any of the evidence nor religious understandings on how life began

Who's this Adam guy you mention?

@Annika the question being "what is the evidence for abiogenesis ?" it can be answered by people who study the topic, by citing, for example, the experiment you referenced. Dunno if those people identify more as biologists or chemists, but it's not a matter of philosophy.

@armand - correct- - what I mean is not the "local abiogenesis" thesis which is very much pure biology (competitor to "seed theory" : life came to Earth from elsewhere). I'm saying the global statement (universal) that all life must come from prior life. It's that particulr formulation that I am saying is not really a question in biology --  yes, somewhere, somehow, life started. Most biologists take that for granted and really care about local abiogenesis.

So you çannot concur as to seeding oŕ life comes from nonlife but you proclaim that as the truth. How dare you!!

If God were not alive could he make decisions that determined our free will. No creation does not have freewill or yes it does. Are you actions determined or are you free to make them independent of god. To be honest I'm in favour of the Greek fates because of the reality of an omniscient God. If God knows how do the fates decide xxxx

You are asking which of the below has evidence of being true:

P1: All life comes from previous life.
P2: Abiogenesis proposes life came from non life.

We can re-phrase P1 as:

for all lifeforms x and times t: If lifeform x began at time t, then there exists another lifeform y who began at some earlier time time q<t-s, where s is some positive constant.

(Edited to address Jo’s edge case)
Since we know there is at least one lifeform existing now, by induction it implies that life must have always been present in the universe.
However - we know that at the earliest epochs of the universe, conditions were so extreme that life could not exist (as defined by biologists).
Therefore, by Modus Tollens, not all life comes from earlier life, which is exactly what abiogenesis is.

Wrong conclusion  The universe exists life exists. Did life come from previous life?. The evidence of this is indisputable. The universe began? had an earlier epoch that would not support life? Unproven and is a weak argument and is not beyond a doubt. What is not beyond doubt is that every peice of life on earth today is the result of prior life. I'll leave it up to you as to how that prior life is defined.

@8Mad0Manc8 i've offered both a potential reducto ad absurdum argument against your first premise (P1) and comments that directly support P2. There is very strong evidence from cosmology and physics that there was a point in time when it is almost certain that no life existed. If you contest that then you'll need to debunk all of cosmology, biology, and chemistry that says that the early universe was uninhabitable.

@@Annika It is not absurd to proclaim that God exists there are countless civilisations that have been convinced that there is a God.. There will be countless more that will. Or do you think this civilisation is the one that will determine the truth without question and every other will follow?

@8Mad0Manc8 -- nowhere did I say the belief that God exists is absurd. You asked about if life can come from non-life, and I gave a couple reasons I think the answer is  yes. You can reject them if you want but then why did you ask the question?

Life did not come from non life. My definition of life is it can create life. As much as that can become an infinite regress etc an angle you did not go down. Christ if I'd come up with an argument that was beyond critism I'd be jesus myself. Since I'm not, we just differ in faith. I have faith you do not have faith or you lack faith. Faith is personal, as is belief in God. I should have known better to project my faith, its just philosophers think they know better and sometimes it gets under my skin. :-)

@8Mad0Manc8 that’s fine but then I think the question wasn’t really a question for you

@Annika The principle of induction works fine for a countable set, but not necessarily for a set of real numbers: Assume that life exists only(!) at the discrete set T of time points
t_n=1+(1/n), n  > 0 a natural number, i.e. t_n = 2, 3/2 ,4/3, 5/4, …
The set T satisfies P1. But most real time points do not belong to T, notably all real times t <=1. Would this be a counter example to your conclusion from P1?

@JoWehler can you spell out the counterexample a bit more — I don’t see it yet

@Annika The counterexample considers a monotonic, strictly decreasing sequence, converging to a finite limit. Each element of the sequence has a smaller member in the sequence. But you cannot make a conclusion about the limit and all smaller points of the ambient set. - If I did not clarify my point please continue inquiring.

@JoWehler — ah ok. I was implicitly assuming that there is a minimum time needed to produce the successor— at some point your example would get below the rate of subatomic particle interactions

@Annika I suspected that you made such an implicit assumption: Assuming a lower bound for the time, which chemical reactions need to organize simple living organism. Under this assumption I agree with your argumentation. - But like you I think: There is no need to further argue about abiogenesis since the experiments of Miller-Urey and also theoretical considerations in the line of Eigen's hypercycle.  – Do you have some good link to micelle formation?

@JoWehler https://www.nsf.gov/news/news_summ.jsp?cntn_id=111652

@JoWehler & Annika Doubt is a perfect reason to believe but not the only one.

@8Mad0Manc8 are you saying “from doubt anything consistent can follow?” — I don’t agree if only because deduction is not the only (and actually not the most widely applicable) form of valid reasoning. Inductive reasoning allows us to evaluate arguments that are not conclusive in terms of coherence, verifiably, transparency, and parsimony. We don’t get the satisfaction of deductive validity but we have managed to make progress nonetheless in other areas of human thought.
